# How I can add variable in the node-red exec/unix command node

Tags: unix, iot, node-red

I wanted to add some variable value (ex. test=test value) at the end of a file with a Unix command. For I wanted to add test value at the end of FILE_NAME.txt. So FILE_NAME.txt would contain test value

```
nano FILE_NAME.txt
```

will show string > 'test value' inside FILE_NAME.txt

```
sudo sed -i -e \$aVARIABLE(VAR_VALUE) /etc/FILE_NAME.txt
```

I tried similar with a node-red text input field node connected to the input of exec node. But didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you are asking but,

If you just want to add lines to a file then the `file-out` node has a mode to append a msg.payload to a given file.

[image]

Else if you  want to execute a command  with a variable appended to the end of the command then the `exec` node will do that.

[image]

Both of these nodes are in the code set (but both are removed from the default Bluemix version as they do not make sense in a PaaS environment)

Comment: yes, I wanted to use exec, (running on local raspberry pi). But do not how to put a variable in the exec command. The variable will come from user input text filed (dashboard node).

Comment: The exec node has an option to add the input `msg.payload` to the end of the command before executing it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. however, I am quite new to node-red don't know how to put that msg.payload in the exec command. Should I put   something like sudo sed -i -e \$amsg.payload /etc/FILE_NAME.txt  OR sudo sed -i -e \$a{msg.payload} /etc/FILE_NAME.txt. I tried both. it didn't work. When I write something like that, I can see that FILE_NAME.txt contains either {msg.payload} or msg.payload depending what I have written.

Comment: no, you put nothing extra in the command, the `msg.payload` will be added to the **end** of the command

Comment: My variable is in the middle of exec command. So, are you suggesting to write two consecutive exec node?

Comment: no, you can't add to the middle, the best you can do is to assemble all the arguments in a function node before the exec node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138428/discussion-between-khalid-and-hardillb).

Comment: Now that was a frustrating end to what I had hoped would give me the same answer. :(

Comment: When  I add "append msg.payload" my test shell script gets "[object" as it's $1 argument ...